# Installing postgresql-10 libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.14+dfsg) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ub

Tags: 16.04, apt, dependencies, postgresql

i'm trying to install postgresql-10 via the instructions listed here:

https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

I'm trying to run this step and I keep getting the following unmet dependency errors:

```
$ sudo apt install postgresql-10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-10 : Depends: postgresql-client-10
                 Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.14+dfsg) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libpq5 (>= 9.3~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm unsure of how to exactly correct these problems, i've tried running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

What is the appropriate way to update these packages to get postgresql-10 installed on my ubuntu 16.04 instance?

EDIT:

when I try manually installing those dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt install libgssapi-krb5-2
[sudo] password for chris: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgssapi-krb5-2 is already the newest version (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @Olimjon https://pastebin.com/YwwrVTVK

Comment: Can you use chain method by using the first unmet package in the list? e.g. `sudo apt install postgresql-client-10` and if it shows "unmet dependencies" again, do this `sudo apt install <first unmet package>` until you encounter different error?

Comment: @Olimjon Editted the OP

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy postgresql-10` to make sure that you selected the right repository? The package version for Xenial has [different dependencies](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/xenial-pgdg/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2) than what your Apt shows. Thanks.